# jQuery rollover - replace background image

Tags: jquery, menu

I have a submenu that slides out when the parent 'li' is hovered and that works ok. I am trying to have the background image of the parent 'li' change when this beahaviour happens.

```
    $(function () {
    $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
    $('nav li').hover(function () {
        //$('this').css('background-image','"url(' + images/arrow.png + ')"');
        $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

The commented line is my failed attempt, but hopefully gives an idea of what I want to try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You string concatenation is wrong

```
$(function () {
    $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
    $('nav li').hover(function () {
        $('this').css('background-image','url(images/arrow.png)');
        $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).css('backgroundImage', 'url(images/arrow.png)')
```

Arun is right about the string concatenation, but you also need to remove the single quotes from *this.*